# svg4everybody not copying external symbol attributes (like fill, stroke, etc) in svg element in IE 11 and EDGE browsers

Tags: svg

My external .svg file contain follows:

```
<symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
```

The plugin works fine but does not copies the fill, stroke and other attributes in the actual HTML page.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support IE 8, consider using [svgxuse](https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse) instead which is a simple polyfill for using `<use>` with reference to an external SVG.